# How do I write a custom start page for VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

I've looked around, and not found much documentation on this, so I thought I'd ask where all the experts hang out.

I would like to create a new start page, with bug tracking and source control interfaces, rather than the standard MSDN feed.  I seem to remember that one can do more than just supply a different URL, but can actually implement a component to run as the start page, which needn't use web content.  I may be wrong.  Can anyone please give me some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do is to create a DTE ToolWindow [(read: Creating a ToolWindow hosting a .NET user control)](http://blogs.msdn.com/hlong/archive/2005/09/30/475887.aspx) and host your controls there, then its pretty easy to create an addin that will show the tool window as a document at runtime. (The same way that the start-up page looks)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Startup and put your RSS URL in the Start Page news channel field.

That should give you enough, but if you want to do more you can select open home page in the at startup dropdown and point it at a URL with the appropriate content. If you use an intranet with Windows authentication you could display user specific stuff.

Comment: I don't want a feed, I want completely different content.

Comment: Also, I actually want the Start page at startup, not any of the other options.

Answer (score 0):

This will be completely customizable in VS 2010. You'll be able to do anything you want to on the start page.